# Laravel passing array to my view via redirect

Tags: php, laravel

I am fairly new to laravel and I am trying to send some data to my view via redirect. This is what my code looks like:

In my controller:

```
$tags = Tag::all();
return Redirect::to('klant/profile/edit')->with('tags', $tags);
```

Now In my view I want to loop over all the tags in a select field. I do this like so:

```
<select name="filterTags" class="form-control" id="tagsDropdown">
   <option value="all">Alle projecten tonen</option>
   @foreach (Session::get('tags') as $tag)
       <option value="{{ $tag->name }}">{{ $tag->name }}</option>
   @endforeach
</select>
```

But I get the error:

> "invalid argument supplied for foreach"

Can anyone help me out?

Any help is appreciated! Many thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not a good way of handling it. Why not fetch `$tags` in the function handling `klant/profile/edit`?

Comment: The error is thrown when there is no flashed `tags` data. You should probably check the existence of the parameter, but why are flashing Eloquent models? That's unusual.

Comment: What's your laravel version? And, did you try dd(Session) ?

Comment: Why do you use Session to get your data ?
Maybe that the reason for yours invalid argument.

Comment: If it's possible return view('view-name')->with(['tags' => $tags]) may be a better solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function index(){
    $tags = Tag::all();
    return view('welcome',compact('tags'))
}
```

Just make sure you've page called `welcome.blade.php` in your `resources/views/` directory

If you wan't to use `with()` function you can use it also instead of compact.

```
return view('welcome')->with('tags','other_variables');
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this error when you don't have tags,  try this in your view:

```
@if ($tags->count())
    @foreach ($tags as $tag)
        ...
    @endforeach
@else
    No tags
@endif
```

Not use redirects at this way. Don't use redirect to show a view, use it to return responses as errors, to return at index page, etc. I wrote an example to try to explain it:

Your index method must be like this:

```
public function index()
{
    // find your object
    $tags = Tag::all();

    // return the view with the object
    return View::make('tags.index')
        ->with('tags', $tags)
}
```

Your edit like must be like this:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    // find your object
    $tag = Tag::find($id);

    // if tag doesn't exist, redirect to index list
    if (!tag)
    {
        return Redirect::route('tags.index')
            ->with('message', "Tag doesn't exist")
    }

    // return the view with the object
    return View::make('tags.edit')
        ->with('tag', $tag)
}
```

More examples at Laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/responses https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views